# show image in table html

Tags: javascript, html, csv, html-table

I need help on this.
Check if the image_file_name exists in html table first then show_image in another cell using javascript.I provided 2 images in down blow. First image contains a image folder where I have a list of images and the second image shows the layout of HTML page

[image floder][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbbgH.png

[HTML page showing the table][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgQ5N.png

```
  <table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Image_id</th>
      <th class="image_file_name">image_file_name</th>
      <th>Image_Text_output </th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th id="show_image">Show_image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>./imagetocsv/img/MessageMediaPhoto-ID-158.jpg</td>
      <td>test 2</td>
      <td>24-09-2021 12:20:47</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>./imagetocsv/img/MessageMediaPhoto-ID-428.jpg</td>
      <td>test 2</td>
      <td>24-09-2021 12:20:47</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, let's break this problem down to smaller ones, so it's easier to tackle it.

We need to:

- Find a column element based on its class/id (`.image_file_name` and `#show_image`)
- Find the index of a column. So we know which data cell (`<td>`) to get based on the index of a header cell (`<th>`)
- Check if an image exists (whether it returns `200` or `404` when we attempt to fetch it)
- Create image elements and append them to the appropriate row/column

Let's create a few helper functions for that:

```js
/**
 * Return the index of the given column.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} column
 * @return {number}
 */
 const getColumnIndex = (column) => {
  const row = column.parentNode;
  const columns = [...row.children];
  return columns.indexOf(column);
}
```

The `getColumnIndex()` function accepts a column (as an `HTMLElement`) and returns its index.

```js
/**
 * Asynchonously check if the file with the given filename exists.
 *
 * @return {Promise<boolean>}
 */
const fileExists = async (filename) => {
  const response = await fetch(filename, { method: 'HEAD' });
  return response.ok;
}
```

The `fileExists()` function is asynchronous (returns a `Promise`). It accepts the image filename and returns a Promise which resolves to a `boolean`, indicating whether the image exists (responded with a `200 OK` status) or not (responded with a non-ok status, i.e. `404 Not Found`).

```js
/**
 * Create an image element with the given URL.
 *
 * @param {string} url
 * @return {HTMLElement}
 */
const createImageElement = (url) => {
  const image = document.createElement('img');
  image.setAttribute('src', url);
  return image;
};
```

The `createImageElement()` function accepts a URL, creates an `<img>` element and returns it.

Now that we have our helper functions, let's write the rest of it. We'll listen for the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) event to make sure the initial HTML document has been completely loaded (i.e. our `<table>` exists).

```js
/**
 * Run the initial HTML document has been completely loaded.
 */
const init = async () => {
  // Do stuff
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

Let's get the table and its rows:

```
// Get the table and its rows
const table = document.querySelector('.dataframe');
const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr');
```

If we know our table's layout we can explicitly set the `image_file_name` and `show_image` indices:

```js
const filenameIndex = 1;
const imageIndex = 4;
```

Otherwise, we can utilize our `getColumnIndex()` function to find them, like this:

```js
// Get the `image_file_name` and `show_image` columns
const filenameColumn = table.querySelector('th.image_file_name');
const imageColumn = table.querySelector('th#show_image');

const filenameIndex = getColumnIndex(filenameColumn);
const imageIndex = getColumnIndex(imageColumn);
```

Finally, we're going to iterate over each row, get the filename, check if that image exists, and display it if it does.

```js
// Iterate over each row
for await (const row of rows) {
  // Get all columns of the currently iterated row
  const columns = row.children;

  // Get the filename
  const filename = columns[filenameIndex].textContent;

  // Check if the image exists
  const imageExists = await fileExists(filename);

  // If it exists
  if (imageExists) {
    // Clear the `show_image` column
    columns[imageIndex].innerHTML = '';

    // Create an image element
    const image = createImageElement(filename);

    // Add the image
    columns[imageIndex].appendChild(image);
  }
}
```

Putting it all together:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Image_id</th>
      <th class="image_file_name">image_file_name</th>
      <th>Image_Text_output </th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th id="show_image">Show_image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>./imagetocsv/img/MessageMediaPhoto-ID-158.jpg</td>
      <td>test 2</td>
      <td>24-09-2021 12:20:47</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>./imagetocsv/img/MessageMediaPhoto-ID-428.jpg</td>
      <td>test 2</td>
      <td>24-09-2021 12:20:47</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /**
    * Return the index of the given column.
    *
    * @param {HTMLElement} column
    * @return {number}
    */
  const getColumnIndex = (column) => {
    const row = column.parentNode;
    const columns = [...row.children];
    return columns.indexOf(column);
  }

  /**
    * Asynchonously check if the file with the given filename exists.
    *
    * @return {Promise<boolean>}
    */
  const fileExists = async (filename) => {
    const response = await fetch(filename, { method: 'HEAD' });
    return response.ok;
  }

  /**
    * Create an image element with the given URL.
    *
    * @param {string} url
    * @return {HTMLElement}
    */
  const createImageElement = (url) => {
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('src', url);
    return image;
  };

  /**
    * Run  the initial HTML document has been completely loaded.
    */
  const init = async () => {
    // Get the table element
    const table = document.querySelector('.dataframe');

    // Get the `image_file_name` and `show_image` columns
    const filenameColumn = table.querySelector('th.image_file_name');
    const imageColumn = table.querySelector('th#show_image');
    
    const filenameIndex = getColumnIndex(filenameColumn);
    const imageIndex = getColumnIndex(imageColumn);

    // Get the table rows
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr');

    // Iterate over each row
    for await (const row of rows) {
      // Get all columns of the currently iterated row
      const columns = row.children;

      // Get the filename
      const filename = columns[filenameIndex].textContent;

      // Check if the image exists
      const imageExists = await fileExists(filename);

      // If it exists
      if (imageExists) {
        // Clear the `show_image` column
        columns[imageIndex].innerHTML = '';

        // Create an image element
        const image = createImageElement(filename);

        // Add the image
        columns[imageIndex].appendChild(image);
      }
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
</script>
```

---

<sub>**Disclaimer:** This answer includes arrow functions, promises, async/await, the spread operator, and other ES6+ features.</sub>

Comment: how do I connect my table.html file to this code?

Comment: @johndiv You can insert your JavaScript in a `<script>` tag in your `.html` file.

Comment: @johndiv I updated my answer to include the HTML code you provided in your question. If it solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted :)

Comment: What does url do and all of my images are in show_image folder. How do I call that in the code

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? What "url" are you referring to?

Comment: const createImageElement = (url) => {
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('src', url);
    return image;
  };

Comment: `createImageElement()` is an arrow function. `url` is a (string) parameter. We're passing the filename (the content of the 2nd column). In your example, `./imagetocsv/img/MessageMediaPhoto-ID-158.jpg` would be treated as a relative URL (relative to the path of your `.html` file)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237532/discussion-between-john-div-and-over-engineer).

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to create an image object in each table row, then set the source to the content of the second column.
To do that we need to give the `tbody` element an `id`, then iterate trought every child of it.

Like this:

```js
function displayPictures(){
    //Get the tbody element
    var tbody=document.getElementById("tbody")
    //For each row
    for (var row of tbody){
        //We create an image object 
        var imageObject=new Image()
        //We set the image source to the 2nd columns content
        imageObject.src=row[1].innerText
        //And finally, we replace the 5th cell's content
        row[4].innerHTML=""
        row[4].appendChild(imageObject)
    }
}
```

To make this a bit more memory efficient, we can declare each local variable in a single `var` statement, like this:

```js
function displayPictures(){
    //Deaclaring variables
    var tbody,row,imageObject
    //Get the tbody element
    tbody=document.getElementById("tbody")
    //For each row
    for (row of tbody){
        //We create an image object 
        imageObject=new Image()
        //We set the image source to the 2nd columns content
        imageObject.src=row[1].innerText
        //And finally, we replace the 5th cell's content
        row[4].innerHTML=""
        row[4].appendChild(imageObject)
    }
}
```

You can easily manipulate the pictures (eg:setting their height and width) right before inserting them.

---

The other method would be to [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the pictures, but it's not necessary, because Cross Origin Resource Sharing policy does not affect simple image queries (as far as I know).

**Edit:**
Over-engineer's Ansver reminded me of the error handling:
You can simply attach an `onerror` handler to the `Image` object, to set the placeholder image or more easily just set an `alt` text which displays when the image fails to show up.

```js
//This sets a placeholder image if any error occours.
imageObject.onerror=function(e){this.src=[path to placeholder image]}
//The alt text is only shown when the image fails to load properly.
//It's mostly used to describe the functionality of the image, but in this case, the 'Not found' is enough.
imageObject.alt="Not found"
```

This method does not rely purely on JS, it uses the HTML's functionality too.

Comment: how do I connect my table.html file to this code?

Comment: You include the script as a `<script defer>[code]</script>` tag in the html's `<head>` element. The `defer` means 'load the script after the page fully loaded', it is needed to avoid errors with the `document.getElementById`. Also, don't forget to call the function.

Comment: is this correct .... function displayPictures() {
            var tbody, row, imageObject
            tbody = document.getElementById("tbody >tr >td")
            for (row of tbody) {
                imageObject.onerror = function (e) { this.src = ['/imagetocsv/img/'] }
                imageObject.alt = "Not found"
                imageObject = new Image()
                imageObject.src = row[2].innerText
                row[5].innerHTML = ""
                row[5].appendChild(imageObject)
            }
        }